# Optional State or Binding in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to ask question about SwiftUI behaviour
when I am using `.onChange( value) { }`

Why If I am using `@State var some: SomeType?` with optional type
and then `@Binding var some: SomeType` this operator only detects changes
it there is change from some SomeType value to nil and vice versa.
But changes to underlying object values are not detected as changes

ex. @Binging var progress: Int?

changing progress from nil to 100 detectes changes
but if I change values from 1 -> 2 -> 3 they are skipped
It works if I use `@Binding var progress: Int`

Any Idea how to use Optionals with onChange() ?

Comment: Works fine here (if bind optional to optional, direct binding non optional to optional is not allowed). Would you provide reproducible demo code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is working example of optional with State and Binding:

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var progress: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        CustomView(progress: $progress)
        
    }
}
```

---

```
struct CustomView: View {
    
    @Binding var progress: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button("update") {
            
            if let unwrappedInt = progress { progress = unwrappedInt + 1 } 
            else { progress = 0 }         //<< █ █ Here: initializing! █ █
            
        }
        .onChange(of: progress) { newValue in
            
            if let unwrappedInt = progress { print(unwrappedInt) }
            
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Yea is works. I've been using Progress? 
then progress.completedUnitCount += 1 doesn't worked.
But creating new instances each time of new let newProgress = .. solved this issue
Int? also doesn't work for me but maybe it doesn't work cause other bug.
If it doesn't work you should create new object instance and assigned it to @State/@Binding

Comment: it doesn't work with Date()

Comment: Hm, if you have an optional value in an object you're trying to display, trying to use it in onUpdate won't compile because "Instance method 'onChange(of:perform:)' requires that 'Binding<String?>' conform to 'Equatable'"